# Mapsforge mapfile for offline use under osmdroid

Tags: android

I want to use a downloaded Mapsforge map-file offline under osmdroid-api. But osmdroid only uses tile-maps (right ?). What's to do ? Is a conversion possible ?

Regards Wicki

Answer (score 4):

No need for conversion.

- if you have Mapsforge map file, then just put file in /sdcard/Yourfile.map
- download [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rem2iz4zlg6e45k/OSMDroidAndMapsforge.zip?dl=0) example,unpack & import as android project and change map file name, lat & long in HybridMap.java class constructor

change dubai.map to yourfile.map and lat/long according to Yourfile.map

```
    useMapsforgeTiles(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+File.separator+"dubai.map");
    center(25.271139000000000000,55.307485000000040000);
```

- if you don't have map file just download [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h98lkykmlpp2g7o/dubai.map?dl=0) map file and put in /sdcard/dubai.map

you can also download maps from

- [Mapsforge server](http://download.mapsforge.org/maps/)
- [Follow this tutorial to create map for your own area.](https://github.com/cgeo/cgeo/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-offline-maps)

Answer (score 1):

Since osmdroid-5.2 the source code at 
https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid
contain the demo app `osmdroid-forge-app` that demonstrates `osmdroid-android` + `osmdroid-mapsforge` to 
show offline map files.